# Python get user input and then assign a string to a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to ask the user to select between options 1-5. Each option will have a different variable for nmap_arguments. Then it will run the function run_nmap.

The issue is it does not seem to be executing the code in the chosen option. It just skips to the next element.

```
import sys
import os
import nmap
from datetime import datetime
import time
import csv
import shutil


#Ask for user input and assign IP\subnet and port range.
print('<' + "-"  * 40 + '>')#style options
ip_range = '192.168.3.132' #str(input('\nEnter an IP or subnet: (Example: 192.168.1.0/24 or 192.168.1.1-50) '))
user_ports = '1-500' #str(input('\nEnter Ports to scan: '))
print("\nScanning IP " + ip_range + ". For ports " + user_ports + ".")

def run_nmap():
    #nmap scan config
    nmap_scan = ("nmap " + ip_range + " -p" + user_ports + " " + nmap_arguments + " -oX outfile.xml")
    #convert xml to csv
    os.system( nmap_scan + '&& python C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\python\\nmap_to_csv.py -f outfile.xml -csv')
    os.system('exit' )
def user_arts():
scanops = input("""Please select the type of nmap scan you would like to run
    1) TCP Connect
    2) SYN ACK Scan
    3) Scan UDP Ports
    4) OS and Services Discovery
    5) Custom \n""")
print("You have chosen: ", scanops)

if scanops == '1':
        nmap_arguments = ' -O '
        run_nmap()
        print(nmap_arguments)
elif scanops == '2':
        nmap_arguments = '-sS'
        run_nmap()
elif scanops == '3':
        nmap_arguments = '-u'
        run_nmap()
elif scanops == '4':
        nmap_arguments = 'A'
        run_nmap()
elif scanops == '5':
        nmap_arguments = '-nse'
        run_nmap()
elif scanops >='6':
        print("Please enter a valid option")
```

I have modified the above code as I think this shows better what I am trying to do.

OMG. my edited code does work, i forgot to remove `def user_arts():`....

Comment: So what's the problem? Please [edit] to clarify. As well you need to provide a [mre], but `O` and `pn` are not defined. See [ask] for other advice.

Comment: I mean I can see a lot of problems with your code, but I'm not sure how to properly approach them without context and a problem statement.

Comment: I know that `nmap_args = str(-pn)` and `return -O` is wrong . I just dont know what is right. And Im not sure I am calling `nmap_arguments = str(user_args)` correctly

Comment: OK, then what are you trying to accomplish in those lines?

Comment: I want each if/elif to be assigned as the value of nmap_arguments

Comment: Am I doing this backwards? Maybe I should make my code a function and call it in each elif?

Comment: Let me be more specific: What are you trying to accomplish with `nmap_args = str(-pn)` and `return -O`? Are they supposed to be strings? i.e. `'-pn'` and `'-O'`? Why is `nmap_args` never used? And what are you trying to accomplish with `nmap_arguments = str(user_args)`? Are you trying to call `user_args`? If so that would be written `nmap_arguments = user_args()`.

Comment: @wjandrea I edited my post, I think now it shows what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Code your input-response pairs into a dictionary and just call that dictionary instead of explicit if-thens.

```
scan_types = {'1': 'TCP Connect', '2': 'SYN ACK Scan', '3': 'Scan UDP Ports', '4': 'OS and Services Discovery', '5': 'Custom'}

def user_args():
    scanops = input("Please select the type of nmap scan ... ")
    try:
        return scan_types[scanops]
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid option")
        return user_args()
```

Let's test:

```
user_args()

Please select the type of nmap scan ... 1
Out[60]: 'TCP Connect'

user_args()

Please select the type of nmap scan ... 2
Out[61]: 'SYN ACK Scan'

user_args()

Please select the type of nmap scan ... 8
Please enter a valid option

Please select the type of nmap scan ... 9
Please enter a valid option

Please select the type of nmap scan ... 3
Out[62]: 'Scan UDP Ports'
```

And at the end, just call this function into your final string, don't mess with any globals:

```
nmap_scan = ("nmap " + ip_range + " -p" + user_ports + " " + user_args() + " -oX outfile.xml")
```

---

**Edit:**

```
scan_types = {'1': ' -O ', '2': '-sS', '3': '-u', '4': 'A', '5': '-nse'}
try: nmap_arguments = scan_types[scanops]
except: print("Please enter a valid option")
run_nmap()
```

Explanation: Instead of if-thens, use the dict data structure. It is tailored for getting you a value based on what key you are looking for. If the key is not one of the allowed numbers (1-5), then prompt the "Please enter a valid option" inside an exception. Then run your main function.

I'd still do this in a better way, but this is as simple and intuitive as it gets in achieving your goal.

Comment: I see how that works, but I think the issue is that it doesnt actually pass the correct informaiton into the nmap_scan. I am posting below a new code that is what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove `def user_arts():` and then it worked as expected... Originally I was trying to assign nmap_arguments with each elif. But instead I had to create a function for my code to run, and call it with the nmap_arguments in each elif.

Comment: Your 5 `if` attempts can be reduced to 1 line, and the flow can be enhanced significantly. Please see my updated answer.